# tidy evaluation question on quoting code using vars()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I'm reading this tidy evaluation document https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-why-how.html and having trouble understanding why the first piece of code here doesn't work and the second does work:

```
starwars %>% summarise_at(ends_with("color"), n_distinct)

starwars %>% summarise_at(vars(ends_with("color")), n_distinct)
```

The first piece of code shows an error message: 'No tidyselect variables were registered'

I gather then that it's not able to find the columns in the starwars dataframe ending with color for some reason.

What is vars() doing to make it find the columns in the starwars dataframe? Is it something to do with the environment it's looking in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vars()` is preventing its arguments from being evaluated right away. If you call it in the console, you'll see it returns blueprints for computing values (i.e. expressions) instead of the values themselves:

```
> dplyr::vars(ends_with("color"))
<list_of<quosure>>

[[1]]
<quosure>
expr: ^ends_with("color")
env:  global
```

These delayed computations are resumed later on, in a context where variables are made available. If you run them right away, the context has not been set and you get a tidyselect error.

Comment: according to `?select_helpers` it works only in selecting functions, why keep it to those though ? what would be the cost of it working in all tidyverse functions ?

Comment: `across()` is coming in dplyr 1.0.0 to bridge data-masking and selections.

Answer (score 1):

`vars(...)` is needed so that the `vars` argument to `ends_with` is filled in properly.  If  you fill it in yourself then you won't need `vars`

```
starwars %>% summarise_at(ends_with("color", vars = names(.)), n_distinct)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  hair_color skin_color eye_color
       <int>      <int>     <int>
1         13         31        15
```